# Android: Keep GPS active

Tags: android, gps

i'm having a main activity that runs a gps listener.
If i'm starting a new activity the listener is destroyed.
I need the gps to be still activated, also after starting the 2nd activity.
Do i have to implement an own listener there, or is there another solution?

Comment: out of curiosity, when would the listener be destroyed?

Comment: Also, can you provide some more context? If your app is designed to sit in the background and react to location changes, you may want to create a service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995311/how-to-keep-gps-turned-on-when-switching-between-activities-but-off-when-when-h

Answer (score 3):

I recommend creating a Service that extends LocationListener.  I would start your Service from your Activity using startService.

Here is an example: http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/simple-android-tracklogging-service.html